# Using the Wifi of a notebook via ethernet for another PC

Tags: linux, routing, wifi, ethernet

I want to connect a PC to the internet via my notebook, which is connected to a WLAN.

The setup should look like the following scheme:
`PC (eth0) -> Notebook (eth0) -> Notebook(wlan0) -> Router`.
Both are running linux - arch on the notebook and funtoo on the PC.

**Edit**: So I tried rush's method and it didn't work for me, here is what I did:

PC:

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.2.3
route add default gateway 192.168.2.2
nameserver 8.8.8.8 > resolv.conf
```

Notebook:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.2.101
```

192.168.2.101 is the wlan0 IP address. I can't ping 192.168.2.2 (connect: Network is unreachable) and the connection doesn't seem to be working anymore on the notebook.

Comment: On notebook, do: # ifconfig eth0 192.168.2.2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's pretty easy. You need to connect PC to notebook. Configure `eth0` on PC (set for example ip = 192.168.2.3 and default gateway 192.168.2.2 and dns server to 8.8.8.8). That's all you need to do on PC.
On notebook you need to set up the internet connection as usual and configure `eth0` with the following way: set ip address to 192.168.2.2, enable net forwarding with iptables.

Hope you're able to set up ip, gw and dns. To set up forwarding execute following script from root user:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
INET="wlan0"
INETIP="$(ifconfig $INET | sed -n '/inet addr/{s/.*addr://;s/ .*//;p}')"
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $INET -j SNAT --to-source $INETIP
```

Watch out any specific iptables rules you're already have.
To disable them you can execute *before* the script above:

```
iptables -F INPUT
iptables -F FORWARD
iptables -F OUTPUT
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

And voila, you have the internet on PC.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, though I didn't manage to get it working. I will edit the topic.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me.